# How to change the date format of the correlated date?

Tags: jmeter

I'm capturing the date in one request so that I can send the captured date as the parameter to next request.
But in the next request the date should be sent with different format.
In order to send the date I need to modify the date format how can do that?

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have `${date}` variable with the value of `27/01/16` and you need to convert it to `January 27, 2016`

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the 2nd request
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


   SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
   SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
   Date date = source.parse(vars.get("date"));
   String newDate = target.format(date);
   vars.put("date", newDate);
   ```

   After above code execution `${date}` variable will hold the new value with the date in different format

See:

- [SimpleDateFormat class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for patterns explained
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for information on Beanshell scripting in Jmeter